# In unity3D, Click = Touch?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, click, touch

I want to detect click/touch event on my gameObject 2D.

And this is my code:

```
void Update()
{
   if (Input.touchCount > 0)
   {
     Debug.Log("Touch");
   }
}
```

`Debug.Log("Touch");` does not show when I click on screen or my gameObject.

Comment: You're on a PC or on a mobile device? On a PC touchCount will always be 0 unless (iirc) you have a touchscreen.

Comment: I'm on a PC and when I clicked touchCount always be 0. That's reason why I asked Click can be considered as Touch in Unity3D.If not, how can I test Touch event on PC?

Comment: It depends if you need multitouch or not. If not, then an onMouseDown could serve as a test.

Comment: @naXa This may be new functionality but I believe using `OnMouseDown()` in a Unity project (Unity 4.6 and Unity 5) has worked for me on my iphone

Comment: OnMouseDown is being triggered by a tap/touch on my iPhone 6+

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Short answer: yes, touch may be handled with `Input.GetMouseButtonDown()`.

- `Input.GetMouseButtonDown()`, `Input.mousePosition`, and associated functions work as tap on the touch screen (which is kind of odd, but welcome). If you don't have a multi-touch game, this is a good way to keep the in-editor game functioning well while still keeping touch input for devices. <sup>(source: [Unity Community](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-iphone-does-a-mouse-click-a-screen-touch.31150/))</sup>
- Mouse simulation with touches can be enabled/disabled with [`Input.simulateMouseWithTouches`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-simulateMouseWithTouches.html) option. By default, this option is enabled.
- Though it is good for testing, I believe `Input.GetTouch()` should be used in production code (because it is able to handle simultaneous touches).
- Interesting approach is to add touch handling to `OnMouseUp()`/`OnMouseDown()` event:

  ```
    //  OnTouchDown.cs
    //  Allows "OnMouseDown()" events to work on the iPhone.
    //  Attach to the main camera.

    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class OnTouchDown : MonoBehaviour {
        void Update () {
            // Code for OnMouseDown in the iPhone. Unquote to test.
            RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
            for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
                if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase.Equals(TouchPhase.Began)) {
                    // Construct a ray from the current touch coordinates
                    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
                    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                        hit.transform.gameObject.SendMessage("OnMouseDown");
                }
        }
    }
  ```

  <sup>(source: [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/262951/android-clicking-to-touch.html#answer-262963))</sup>

**UPD.:** There is [Unity Remote](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html) mobile app for simulating touching in editor mode (works with Unity Editor 4 and Unity Editor 5).

Comment: Tks you so much. This is Bart's answer: "You're on a PC or on a mobile device? On a PC touchCount will always be 0 unless (iirc) you have a touchscreen". Because touchCount always be 0 on PC so I can only test your code on device?

Comment: @Lnitus, yes. you can use OnMouse-events and `Input.GetMouseButtonDown()` to handle both: mouse and touch events. But you can use `Input.touchCount` (and functions related to touch) **only** for touch-events.

Comment: "Though it is good for testing, I believe Input.GetTouch() should be used in production code" ... why do you believe this? I'm using Unity 2019 and it seems to work fine for click (touch) and right click (two finger touch), but if there's a real reason, I'd like to save time and use touch directly.

Comment: @GioAsencio it was sooo long ago... I don't remember the exact reason for writing this. now I just checked out [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-simulateMouseWithTouches.html) and I see that `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` is restricted to 3 touches (corresponding to 2 mouse buttons). and with `Input.GetTouch` we're able to handle more touches (usually consumer devices support up to 10 simultaneous touches).

Comment: @GioAsencio back then, I probably used this old answer as a reference -> http://answers.unity.com/answers/178557/view.html (it contains the same advice about production)

Comment: Thanks, though I still don't see any problem with it except confusion. If you use a device with touch screen it wont cause a mouse click any other way, and even if it did, the mouse would simply have less options (so you could implement both, and there wouldn't be an issue). As of the GUI, it has single rays regardless. The touchCount and GetTouch still works. The only thing I could see is if you needed 4 or more simultaneous touches, which isn't often.

Answer (score 26):

From what I understand the Unity player does not allow you to trigger touch events, only mouse events.

But you can simulate fake touch events based on the mouse events, as explained in this blog post: http://2sa-studio.blogspot.com/2015/01/simulating-touch-events-from-mouse.html

```
void Update () {
    // Handle native touch events
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
        HandleTouch(touch.fingerId, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position), touch.phase);
    }

    // Simulate touch events from mouse events
    if (Input.touchCount == 0) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) ) {
            HandleTouch(10, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), TouchPhase.Began);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) ) {
            HandleTouch(10, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), TouchPhase.Moved);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) ) {
            HandleTouch(10, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), TouchPhase.Ended);
        }
    }
}

private void HandleTouch(int touchFingerId, Vector3 touchPosition, TouchPhase touchPhase) {
    switch (touchPhase) {
    case TouchPhase.Began:
        // TODO
        break;
    case TouchPhase.Moved:
        // TODO
        break;
    case TouchPhase.Ended:
        // TODO
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no, there is a **unity remote** android app ([remote app](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html)) for simulating touching in editor mode. I think this maybe helpful.

> The old android app was deprecated. go to [related document](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html) for further information, and it now supports iOS and tvOS as well.

Comment: They also have an iOS app. This was the answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Late but this may help somebody :)

To detect touch and swipe (Mouse not detected in this example - and also just single touch)

Tested with Unity 5.6 on windows 8.1 (with touch screen) and android.

I think you should handle mouse click separately. And also i have no idea about ios.

```
    bool isTouchMoved = false;
    float touchMoveThreshold = .5f;
    Vector3 posA, posB;

    void handleTouch ()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
            if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                posA = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.GetTouch (0).position);            
            } else if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
                isTouchMoved = true;
            } else {
                posB = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.GetTouch (0).position);
                float dx = Mathf.Abs (posA.x - posB.x);
                float dy = Mathf.Abs (posA.y - posB.y);
                if (isTouchMoved && (dx > touchMoveThreshold || dy > touchMoveThreshold)) {
                    Debug.Log ("Swiped");
                    if (dx > dy) {
                        if (posA.x < posB.x) {
                            Debug.Log ("Left to Right");
                        } else {
                            Debug.Log ("Right to Left");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (posA.y > posB.y) {
                            Debug.Log ("Top to Bottom");
                        } else {
                            Debug.Log ("Bottom to Top");
                        }
                    }
                } else if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
                    Debug.Log ("Touched");

                    Vector2 pos2D = new Vector2 (posB.x, posB.y);
                    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (pos2D, Vector2.zero);
                    //RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (Input.GetTouch (0).position, Vector2.zero);
                    if (hit.collider != null) {
                        Debug.Log ("Touched " + hit.collider.name);
                    }
                }
                isTouchMoved = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note(1):** To detect touch on GameObject you should add 2D collider on that GameObject.

**Note(2):** Put **HandleTouch()** in **Update()** function.

---

**Update:** To handle Mouse

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666526/how-to-detect-which-gameobject-is-clicked/60666914#60667013):

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
   Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
   RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction);
   if (hit.collider != null) {
      Debug.Log ("CLICKED " + hit.collider.name);
   }
}
```