# how to detect which gameobject is clicked

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I want to know which gameobject is clicked with mouse on a 2D project

I used

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            clickTime = DateTime.Now;
            mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction);

            if (hit != null && hit.collider != null)
            {


            }

        }
}
```

but it never goes in the second if condition

EDIT: I am working on a single script and access all gameobject from there using GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag() and as I understand thats why the collider code in main script doesnt triggered.
I added a screenshot my code is in GameObject
[image]

Comment: so draw the ray on using the debug tools and see where your ray line is going

Comment: @BugFinder I did. whether it is a button or image cannot get any info about clicked gameobject from hit

Comment: Did you set a collider on your game object ??

Comment: `hit != null` will always be `true` since it is a `struct`. So it seems `hit.collider` is never `true` .. you probably don't have any collider on the object you are trying to click on

Comment: @eomer your Edit doesn't explain anything ... using `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag()` is completely independent and has nothing to do with your `Physics2D.Raycast` ... if you think it is essential please add the full script of how and where you use your stuff exactly

Comment: @derHugo what I was trying to explain is I did not write code for every game object. I have a single script whic contains all the code

Comment: @eomer this is fine ... and still all your individual objects will need collider components attached to them, otherwise the Raycast can't hit anything ...

Comment: @derHugo I have collider components at which gameobject I need to know if it is clicked

Comment: collider **2D** components? Could you show us a Screenshot maybe?

Answer (score 3):

This method works perfect on both desktop and mobile apps:

1. Add a collider component to each object you want to detect its click event.
2. Add a script to your project (let's name it **MyObject.cs**).
   This script must implement the **IPointerDownHandler** interface and its method. And this script must add the **Physics2DRaycaster** to the camera. The whole body of this script could be like this:

   ```
   public class MyObject : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
   {
       private void Start()
       {
           AddPhysics2DRaycaster();
       }

       public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
       {
           Debug.Log("Clicked: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);
       }

       private void AddPhysics2DRaycaster()
       {
           Physics2DRaycaster physicsRaycaster = FindObjectOfType<Physics2DRaycaster>();
           if (physicsRaycaster == null)
           {
               Camera.main.gameObject.AddComponent<Physics2DRaycaster>();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the MyObject.cs script to every object you want to detect click on it. After that, when you click on those objects, their name will display on Console.
4. Make sure that **EventSystem** exists in your project's Hierarchy. If not, add it by right click.

**P.S.** The MyObject.cs script now has **IPointerDownHandler**. This detects click as soon as you touch the objects. You also can use **IPointerUpHandler** and **IDragHandler** for different purposes!

and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I did all but OnPointerDown doesnt triggered

Comment: Dont know why but I am not the only one having trouble cannot work the handlers

Comment: I'm pretty sure its working for me. Recently I checked it again and its OK. Please test it on a new GameObject in your project and do exactly all 4 parts.

Comment: This wasn't working for me because my objects were 3D. If you remove the 2D from the raycaster so its just PhysicsRaycaster, this answer works for 3D objects.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a raycast you should set a **collider** on your sprite

```
private void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
   {
      Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
      RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction);

      if (hit.collider != null) {
         Debug.Log ("CLICKED " + hit.collider.name);
      }
   }
}
```

This is working for me in unity 5.6

[image]

**Note:** "LeftClick" is just a "GameObject" nothing else, I called it like this for better identification :)

---

**EDITED**

I test this method for the UI button but it's not working; so I used a different approach. For the UI button you can add a listener like this:

```
GameObject.Find ("YourButtonName").GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (() => {

});
```

Comment: thanks but I have to write this code in gameobjects own script.
but I am working on a single script which is in an empty object with the same hierarchy of camera and cant access the collision from there. if I write your script to gameobject itself how can the main script know ?

Comment: @eomer you know what colliders are, do you? If there is no `Collider2D` component on your object then `Physics2D.Raycast` can never hit anything. Your script will "know" because then `hit.collider` will be set to the object you actually hit .. which is currently not any

Comment: @Shamshirsaz.Navid I edited your code so it is better to understand for OP what was changed

Comment: I have collider2D component but my script is not in gameobject itself. I added an empty object which has script in it and do all my code from there and added your code there.
in update method if I put breakpoint in Input.GetMousebuttondown(0) it stops when I click on gameobject but nothings happend after that

Comment: @eomer i think this is not important where your script is :) i used this in Update method - and i use a single script also

Comment: @eomer Try making a new empty Unity2D project and test it there. Just for better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple Solution from my side to get current selected gameObject Data.

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
   
public class Level1Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject MyButtonCurrent;
    // Assign this to all GameObject what you want to chec then when you click
    public void myBtn()
    {
        // Simple as that
        MyButtonCurrent = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used BoxCollider instead of BoxCollider2D, then

```
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
    {
        // hit contains the info about object
    }
```

After struggling for ages thinking that because the game is 2D I must use a 2D collider and physics, this worked first time and nothing else was required. I'm fairly new to Unity so I have no clear idea why.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using `OnMouseOver()` method ([docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html)):

```
private void OnMouseOver() {
    if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) return;

    // Your logic here.
}
```

This method only works with collider attached to gameobject, just like Raycast.

It would be cleaner and slightly more performant because there are no multiple `Update()` methods to iterate each frame. Something to keep in mind if you have dozens or hundreds of clickable objects.

(Although there are reports that this method doesn't work with multiple cameras one of which is ortographic one, in which case it is not an option for you.)

Comment: `It would be cleaner and slightly more performant because there are no multiple Update() methods to iterate each frame. Something to keep in mind if you have dozens or hundreds of clickable objects.` Yes but it is possible that OP does the raycast only in one single component which would be clean and efficient as well ;)

Comment: thanks but I have to write this code in gameobjects own script.
but I am working on a single script which is in an empty object with the same hierarchy of camera and cant access the collision from there. if I write your script to gameobject itself how can the main script know ?

Comment: @eomer ah, I see. In that case you'll have to either: 1) create and assign reference to main script manually via inspector for each gameobject, 2) make main script globally visible (static/singleton/service location), or 3) introduce event subscription/triggering system. These systems definitely could be beneficial in other game modules, but it's up to you whether you want to introduce new complex systems in your project or not. If you want simple logic on collider click, better stick to Raycast version.